# Lion + Homebrew: how to fix "config" scripts?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, osx-lion, homebrew

When I run `brew doctor`, I get the output:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick++-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/MagickCore-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/MagickWand-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Wand-config
Warning: Your XQuartz () is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.4.
```

How can I fix it or, am I missing something important?

**EDIT:** I believe this is the reason why I cannot install the `rmagick` library. While its installation I am getting this error message: `an't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix the issue is to remove the "config" scrips out of your $PATH variable. Deleting that install of ImageMagick will do that. You could always reinstall it with brew.

Keep in mind that this might cause issues if you have other software dependent on that specific location of ImageMagick.